# Rails: validates_length_of :allow_nil does not allow nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, null

Using: Rails 3.0.3.

I am using this code in the validator:

```
validates_length_of :birth_date_8, :minimum => 8, :allow_nil => true, :message => "value_is_not_a_proper_date", :if =>:family_birthday?
```

It does not, however, allow the field to be nil. I have checked so it is not a matter of the `:if => :family_birthday?` that is messing things up.

Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: Try allow_blank instead of allow_nil - and if that doesn't help, I would use validates_format and match a regex - some of the rails validations simply don't accept allow_nil and it's not terribly well documented

Comment: Thanks. Allow_nil did the trick. Write that as an answer and I can give you credit for it!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try `allow_blank` instead of `allow_nil` :-)

Comment: It's a good practice to add back-ticks around "language" (key)words. I've edited them in for you.